# function eval in config file with config.py module

Tags: python, configuration, config

I have a configuration file with parameters that are functions of sin and cos.  For convenience, it is useful for me to simply code these parameters as the expressions that define them rather than their resulting values.

This is obviously supported if I use .py config files, but I am investigating using the [config.py](https://www.red-dove.com/config-doc/) Python module instead.  However, it appears that while this module allows use of custom namespaces, it only allows evaluation of attributes in the namespace, not function calls.  For example, if I add the numpy namespace as np, this is allowed:

```
 pi:  `np.pi`
```

But this is not:

```
 x: 0.1
 sin_of_x: `np.sin($x)`
```

I'm guessing this is for security reasons, so malicious users couldn't insert malicious code by adding a namespace with a malicious function.  Is there any way around this, or is the python as configuration file approach the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the [`config`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/config/0.3.9) module per se, but imagine you could easily do something similar to what's shown below using the built-in `ConfigParser` (or `configparser` in Python 3) module.

Given this config file:

```
[Section1]
x: 0.1
sin_of_x: math.sin(x)
```

And this code:

```
import ConfigParser
import math

parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('eval_config.cfg')

namespace = {'__builtins__': None, 'math': math}
for name, value in parser.items('Section1'):
    value = eval(value, namespace)
    print('{!r} = {!r}'.format(name, value))
    namespace[name] = value
```

Output:

```
'x' = 0.1
'sin_of_x' = 0.09983341664682815
```

If you don't want to hardcode the name of modules, you could add a separate `[Modules]` section to the configuration file to define them before use.